# JS click event triggering twice

Tags: javascript, dom

Getting a click event twice on the same element on this code and not use why

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

        console.log("click");
        
        if (!event.target.closest('.expand')) return;

        console.log("clicked me");

    }, false);
```

console on one click:
click x 2
clicked me x 2

Comment: Code lacks for detailing. Can you please provide more details as it is not clear what is issue you are facing from above code.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: There's not much context here, but this specific code shouldn't log two clicks, so you might be adding the event (running this code) twice. `console.log('event added')` right before you add the event and see if it prints twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are **adding the event listener twice**. Put a breakpoint or a log message to the line before `document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {`

Answer (score 0):

seemed that adding the code wrapped oike the following was adding the code in memory twice event though it was on the page once... very strange, any anwser to this issue would be cool.

```
(window.onload = function () {
  // code here
})();
```

Comment: Actually, it is not adding the code twice. There is something called Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Sure, I understandd what an iife is, but how is it that the eventlistener is being added twice in this instance... another mad quirk of JavaScript maybe?

Comment: did you try without "iife"? Probably, even if you didn't put "iife" your code will be executed once. I'm not sure. Whenever you add an event listener, (here you are adding an event listener to `onload` event), it will listen unless you explicitly remove it.

Answer (score -1):

If your issue is to set a click twice event on an elements before it render it's function, use

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) { code.... } )
```